# Multiple Iteration in for-loop using jQuery html() instead of document.write

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have three set of arrays which I got from looping and sorting json data. Let's say, **arr1**, **arr2**, **arr3**. I want to output those arrays combined with HTML codes five times. So far, I have this code:

```
  var max=5;
  for (var b = 0;b < max;b++) {
    var conEl = $('#container');
    var newConEl = conEl.html();
    newConEl = '<ul>';
    var newProp = '<li><span><a href="'+arr1[b]+'">'+arr2[b]+'</a><span>'+arr3[b]+'</span></span></li>';
    newConEl += newProp + '</ul>';
    return conEl.html(newConEl);
  }
```

However, this only outputs one result. This is the result:

```
<div>
  <span>
   <a href="#link-to-result-1">result-1-title</a>
   <span>view-count-1</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

While, I want to have five output. My desired result is:

```
<div>
  <span>
   <a href="#link-to-result-1">result-1-title</a>
   <span>view-count-1</span>
  </span>
  <span>
   <a href="#link-to-result-2">result-2-title</a>
   <span>view-count-2</span>
  </span>
  <span>
   <a href="#link-to-result-3">result-3-title</a>
   <span>view-count-3</span>
  </span>
  <span>...</span>
</div>
```

I got my desired output (five outputs) when using **document.write(newProp);**. But, I do not want to use document.write method.

Comment: That line `var newConEl = conEl.html();` is followed immediately by `newConEl = '<div>';` - that second line will overwrite the value of the variable.

Comment: Meaning, I should move `var newProp = '<li><span><a href="'+arr1[b]+'">'+arr2[b]+'</a><span>'+arr3[b]+'</span></span></li>';
    newConEl += newProp + '</div>';` on the top of that? I have done so, but the result is the same as my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues there:

1. You have the `return` in the wron gplace, so your loop is ending after just one iteration.
2. You're *overwriting* `newConEl` on each loop.
3. You're *overwriting* `newConEl` *within* the loop as well (you have two lines both doing `newConEl =`, one right after another).
4. You're doing an opening and closing `div` tag on each iteration, whereas your question shows your desired result just has one `div` around the whole thing.
5. You're grabbing the old HTML of `conEl` repeatedly in the loop; I don't see any reason to grab that old HTML *at all*.
6. You can't have a `li` as a direct child of a `div`, and there are no `li`s in your listed desired result, but you're including `li` entries in your HTML.

If you set `newConEl` to `"<div>"` to start with, then *append* to it (`+=`), then add the final `"</div>"` at the end and set that on the element (not *retrieving* its current HTML), you should get what you're expecting:

```
var max = 5; // <== Are you really sure arr1, arr2, and arr3 all have at least 5 entries?
var newConEl = '<div>';
for (var b = 0; b < max; b++) {
    newConEl += '<span><a href="'+arr1[b]+'">'+arr2[b]+'</a><span>'+arr3[b]+'</span></span>';
}
newConEl += '</div>';
return $("#container").html(newConEl);
```

Or if you're open to using something a bit more modern; note that this assumes that `arr1`, `arr2`, and `arr3` are all the same length and that you want all of their entries, not just five:

```
return $("#container").html(
    "<div>" +
    arr1.reduce(function(html, entry, i) {
        return html + '<span><a href="' + entry + '">' + arr2[i] + '</a><span>' + arr3[i] + '</span></span>';
    }, "") +
    "</div>"
);
```

Comment: Great! This works, sir. I come with your first solution. Now, I gain some new insight in javascript. About, the `<li>` inside the `<div>`, the `<div>` was actually `<ul>` :D. Thanks in advance for your assist!